# jQuery SlideUp and SlideDown is not working properly

Tags: jquery

I am working on a simple login registration form where login and registration stayed in one page. initially registration portion is hidden. When I click registration then login portion will be up using slideup and registration will be down using slideDown. And vice versa with login.

But somehow it's not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$("#signup").click(function(){
 $("#log").slideUp("slow", function(){
   $("#reg").slideDown("slow");
 });
 
});

// $("#signin").click(function(){
//  $("#reg").slideUp("slow", function(){
//   $("#log").slideDown("slow");
//  });
// });


});
```

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

form {
 text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
 background: url("../img/bg/note.jpeg");
 background-size: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 900px;
}

.login_box { 
 position: relative;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 top: 7%;
 width: 35%;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #EDEDED;
 border-radius: 7px;
 padding: 5px;
 opacity: 0.95;

}

.login_header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #3498db;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 border-top-left-radius: 7px;
 border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}

input[type='submit']{
 background-color: #3498db;
 border: 1px solid #3498db;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
 padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
 color: #2C6C96;
 text-shadow: #7386E2 0.5px 0.5px 0;
 font-size: 100%;
}

input[type='text'],input[type='email'],input[type='password'] {
 border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 margin-top: 5px;
 width: 70%;
 height: 35px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 5px;
}

input[type='text']:hover,input[type='email']:hover,input[type='password']:hover { 

 border-color: #3498db;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #3498db;
}

#reg {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log">
 <form action="register.php" method="POST">
  <input type="email" name="log_email" placeholder="Email" required>
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="log_pass" placeholder="Password">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
  <br>
  <a href="" id="signup" class="signup">Need an account? Register Here!</a>
  <br>
 </form>
 </div>
<br>
 <div id="reg">
 <form action="register.php" method="POST">

 <input type="text" name="reg_fname" placeholder="First Name" required>

 <br> 
 <input type="text" name="reg_lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>

 <br>

 <input type="email" name="reg_email" placeholder="Email" required>


 <br>
 <input type="password" name="reg_pass" placeholder="Password" required>
 <br>
 <input type="password" name="reg_con_pass" placeholder="Confirm password" required>

 <br>
 <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
 <br>
 <a href="" id="signin" class="signin">Already have an account? Login Here!</a>
 <br>


 </form>
 </div>
```

Here is my code in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/moshiurse/pen/jvYVaK)

Comment: sorry, I couldn't added link .And I didn't understand the hint showing . That's why i separate the link to post it . i don't know how to add codepen link properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this in your code

```
<span id="signin" class="signin">Already have an account? Login Here!</span>
```

`<a>` do refresh page.

another way.

```
$("#signup").click(function(event){
    $("#log").slideUp("slow", function(){
         $("#reg").slideDown("slow");
    });
    // event prevent!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks .It works for me . I will mark it as useful .

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can make it work, notice the change in the links `href`:

By using `<a href="#id">` you prevent the default reload and if your JS and CSS don't load, it will scroll to the correct part of the HTML.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#signup").click(function(e){
    $("#log").slideUp("slow", function(){
       $("#reg").slideDown("slow");
    });
  });
  
  $("#signin").click(function(e){
    $("#reg").slideUp("slow", function(){
       $("#log").slideDown("slow");
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

form {
 text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
 background: url("../img/bg/note.jpeg");
 background-size: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 900px;
}

.login_box { 
 position: relative;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 top: 7%;
 width: 35%;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #EDEDED;
 border-radius: 7px;
 padding: 5px;
 opacity: 0.95;

}

.login_header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #3498db;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 border-top-left-radius: 7px;
 border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}

input[type='submit']{
 background-color: #3498db;
 border: 1px solid #3498db;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
 padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
 color: #2C6C96;
 text-shadow: #7386E2 0.5px 0.5px 0;
 font-size: 100%;
}

input[type='text'],input[type='email'],input[type='password'] {
 border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 margin-top: 5px;
 width: 70%;
 height: 35px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 5px;
}

input[type='text']:hover,input[type='email']:hover,input[type='password']:hover { 

 border-color: #3498db;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #3498db;
}

#reg {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log">
 <form action="register.php" method="POST">
  <input type="email" name="log_email" placeholder="Email" required>
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="log_pass" placeholder="Password">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
  <br>
  <a href="#reg" id="signup" class="signup">Need an account? Register Here!</a>
  <br>
 </form>
 </div>
<br>
 <div id="reg">
 <form action="register.php" method="POST">

 <input type="text" name="reg_fname" placeholder="First Name" required>

 <br> 
 <input type="text" name="reg_lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>

 <br>

 <input type="email" name="reg_email" placeholder="Email" required>


 <br>
 <input type="password" name="reg_pass" placeholder="Password" required>
 <br>
 <input type="password" name="reg_con_pass" placeholder="Confirm password" required>

 <br>
 <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
 <br>
 <a href="#log" id="signin" class="signin">Already have an account? Login Here!</a>
 <br>


 </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for me . I didn't realize that giving an id is important there. actually I noticed this. I didn't even care about this. thanks again. I will mark it as helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your html tag

```
<a href="" id="signin" class="signin">Already have an account? Login Here!</a>
```

to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="signin" class="signin">Already have an account? Login Here!</a>
```